# Why is fast lookup possible for dict.items()?

Tags: python, dictionary, hashtable

Suppose we have a dictionary `d` defined as follows

```py
d = {i:i for i in range(1,1000001)}
```

And then we store `d.items()` in `x`. So, `x` is a collection of tuples that contain key-value pairs for each element of `d`. I made a list with the same tuples, defined as follows :

```py
l = [(i, i) for i in range(1,1000001)]
```

Now, I compared the time taken to execute `(1000001, 1000001) in x` and `(1000001, 1000001) in l`. The time difference was very significant. I assumed that this was because `x` had a set-like behavior and implemented hash tables on tuples, as tuples are hashable as well.

However, tuples that contain lists are non hashable, so I tried the same thing with this dictionary :

```py
d = {i:[i,i+1] for i in range(1,1000001)}
```

Unlike what I expected, it still enabled fast lookup.

How does this work?

PS : Here's my code for time comparison

```py
import time

def for_dict_items(n):
    #d = {i:i for i in range(1, n+1)}
    d = {i:[i, i+1] for i in range(1, n+1)}
    di = d.items()
    st = time.time()
    x = (n, [n, n+1]) in di
    et = time.time()
    return (et - st)


def for_tuples_list(n):
    #l = [(i, i) for i in range(1, n+1)]
    l = [(i,[i, i+1]) for i in range(1, n+1)]
    st = time.time()
    x = (n, [n, n+1]) in l
    et = time.time()
    return (et - st)


k = 1000000

t1 = for_dict_items(k)
t2 = for_tuples_list(k)

print(t1, t2, t2/t1, sep = "\n")
```

Comment: `d = {i:[i,i+1] for i in range(1,1000001)}` has integer keys which are hashable; the keys are hashed not the associate values(a List in this case).

Comment: Right, so when I execute `(n,n) in d.items()`, does it basically do `d[n] == n`?

Comment: _"So, x is a collection of tuples"_ - I think it would be more correct to say it is a view of a dictionary. And lookups in dictionaries are done in constant time.

Comment: @zvone I don't think I fully understand what views are in python. Are there any other instances where they're used?

Comment: A `dict_items` value is not just a collection of tuples, despite what the *string representation* of the value might lead you to believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since dict is one of the most important core objects, it's implemented in C, as well as `dict_values`, `dict_keys` and `dict_items`. Here's the CPython [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0634201f5391242524dbb5225de37f81a2cc1826/Objects/dictobject.c#L6332) of `dictitems_contains`:

```c
static int
dictitems_contains(PyObject *self, PyObject *obj)
{
    _PyDictViewObject *dv = (_PyDictViewObject *)self;
    int result;
    PyObject *key, *value, *found;
    if (dv->dv_dict == NULL)
        return 0;
    if (!PyTuple_Check(obj) || PyTuple_GET_SIZE(obj) != 2)
        return 0;
    key = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(obj, 0);
    value = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(obj, 1);
    result = PyDict_GetItemRef((PyObject *)dv->dv_dict, key, &found);
    if (result == 1) {
        result = PyObject_RichCompareBool(found, value, Py_EQ);
        Py_DECREF(found);
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you don't speak C, here's what it does:

- Check that view is correct - namely that it has a reference to the underlying dictionary (and return False if not, for some reason)
- Check the input: if it's not a 2-tuple, return False.
- Look up a key in the underlying dictionary.
- If found, check if value matches. If it does, return True.
- Otherwise, return False.

The core of this is the fact that `dict.items` returns not a list, but a special `dict_items` *view*. The term *view* here means that it does not represent a copy, but only a proxy to retrieve underlying items in some specific way. The same applies to `dict_keys` and `dict_values`, you can read more in the excellent [documentation page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) on this topic.

Note that this is specific to CPython implementation and may be wrong for other implementations.

Comment: It feels like this misses the most important part, which is how the view data structure organizes things so that it's fast.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans nothing really interesting there: a view just stores a reference to the underlying dictionary and operates on it, basically wrapping your requests with dict operations. "Why is dict in python so fast" is at least another question, likely too broad to be answered at once. `dict_view.__contains__` performs the lookup on the dictionary, no other magic involved.

Comment: `t in d.items()` is basically equivalent to `t[0] in d and d[t[0]] == t[1]`. The `dict_items` value doesn't store anything directly; it just translates a query from one form to another.